# cannot implicity convert type System.Collections.GenericList<AnonymousType#1>

Tags: c#, linq

Please have patience with me I'm new to linq and have a question about a couple of errors that I am not understanding any help would be greatly appreciated.

1. the error I am receiving in the title of my question.
2. my childproduct variable returns every single character indiviuallly I would like them to be a string version of the productId and Childtext parameters.

Code:

```
public class AOAPlusChildModel
{
    public List<string> LongName { get; set; }
    public List<string> Text { get; set; }
    public List<string> ProductId { get; set; }

    public static List<AOAPlusChildModel> GetChildProducts() 
    {
        List<AOAPlusChildModel> cp = new List<AOAPlusChildModel>();

        List<AoaUserDefinedVWGetAOAPlusProducts> ChildProductsLists = AoaSvcClient.Client.Context.AoaUserDefinedVWGetAOAPlusProductss.Where(a => a.MasterProductFlag == false && a.Affiliate == "VA").ToList();

        var childProducts = ChildProductsLists.SelectMany(p => p.LongName, (id, childtext) =>
                                                 new { ProductId = id.ProductId, Text = childtext }).ToList();
        cp = childProducts.ToList();                               

        return cp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry not sure if my complete question posted also my childProducts variable returns my ProductId,Test parameters one charterer at a time.

Comment: As for the second question what is `AoaUserDefinedVWGetAOAPlusProducts`? You need to show that class structure

Comment: AoaUserDefinedVWGetAOAPlusProducts is a web service ProductId data type is long Text is string datatype

Comment: Try to not ask two questions in one question. If you ask one question per posted question, you are more likely to get a good answer to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `cp` is a `List<AOAPlusChildModel>` but the linq query is projecting an anonymous type. Instead of creating a new anonymous type create a new `AOAPlusChildModel`

```
return ChildProductsLists.SelectMany(p => p.LongName, 
                                     (id, childtext) =>
                                        new AOAPlusChildModel { 
                                            ProductId = id.ProductId, 
                                            Text = childtext }).ToList();
```

---

Reason for following errors are that you perform `ChildProductsLists.SelectMany(p => p.LongName)` which basically now returns a collection of strings - this collection of strings you are trying to assign as a new `AOAPlusChildModel` object which does not hold `string` properties but `List<string>` properties.

I think your model should look like:

```
public string LongName { get; set; }
public string Text { get; set; }
public string ProductId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you now I am receiving an error with my parameters Cannot convert implicitly convert type long to System.Collections.GenericList<string> for ProductId. and same for childtext but the convert type is char where am i going wrong here?

Comment: @shermanb - your model structure is strange - it seems like each `AOAPlusChildModel` should have a single value for each of it's properties and not a list. Are you sure you want it to be a list?

Comment: @shermanb, you went only wrong at one point: You are not looking at your own source code, nor putting a little effort into trying to comprehend what the source code (and the error message) is telling you. The Linq query accesses the product ids from _AoaUserDefinedVWGetAOAPlusProducts_ objects (`AoaUserDefinedVWGetAOAPlusProducts.ProductID`) - which is a long (as told by the error message) - and wants to assign this long to `AOAPlusChildModel.ProductID` which you have declared to be of type `List<string>`. Now, what did you do wrong...?

Comment: @GiladGreen, according to the error he got, the ProductId should perhaps not be string ;-)

Comment: @elgonzo - ops true :)

Comment: @shermanb - what does `AoaUserDefinedVWGetAOAPlusProducts` contain?

Comment: Yes you are right thank you. i need only to change the data types to match my query.

Comment: @shermanb - Please consider marking question as solved by answer :)